# cannot get the data within HTML tag

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

cannot get the data within HTML tag "alt"=

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup=BeautifulSoup("""<div class="couponTable">
    <div id="tgCou1" class="tgCoupon couponRow"><span class="spBtnMinus"></span><!-- react-text: 67 -->Wednesday Matches<!-- /react-text --></div>
    <div class="cflag"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_JLC.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Japanese League Cup" title="Japanese League Cup" class="cfJLC"></div>
    <div class="cflag"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_JLC.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Japanese League Cup" title="Japanese League Cup" class="cfJLC"></div>
    </div></div></div>""")

lines=soup.find_all('div')
line in lines:print(re.findall('\w+',line['alt'])[0])
```

Comment: You're already using beautifulsoup to get the div. Why would you then use regex?

Comment: `for div in lines:
 imgs = div.find_all("img")
 for img in imgs:
  print(img['alt'])`

Comment: thanks, dears, solved @DanielRoseman

Comment: thanks, dears, solved @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only the `alt` value then it is better for you to get the `img` tag rather than the `div` tag. Also there is no need to use regex to extract the `alt` value

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup=BeautifulSoup("""<div class="couponTable">
<div id="tgCou1" class="tgCoupon couponRow"><span class="spBtnMinus"></span><!-- react-text: 67 -->Wednesday Matches<!-- /react-text --></div>
<div class="cflag"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_JLC.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Japanese League Cup" title="Japanese League Cup" class="cfJLC"></div>
<div class="cflag"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_JLC.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Japanese League Cup" title="Japanese League Cup" class="cfJLC"></div>
</div></div></div>""",'html.parser')

lines=soup.find_all('img')
for line in lines:
    print(line['alt'])
```

Output

> Japanese League Cup
>   Japanese League Cup